# Facebook share custom text

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there something similar to the following to share custom text on facebook timelines?

href="http://twitter.com/home?status=I've%20made%20a%20@candyland%20SOS%20call.%20They're%20making%20the%20world%20a%20better%20place,%20100%20bags%20of%20%5BSWEET%20NAMES%5D%20at%20a%20time:%20">

Answer (score 1):

There's the sharer, this is an [example link](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com)

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com
```

**Edit:** Besides sharing links with customized names or descriptions, there's no possibility to change the post message. It worked about 2 years ago AFAIK, but got removed by Facebook. Even using the Feed Dialog, you can't customize the message.